# CakePhp object error

Tags: cakephp

I uploaded a CakePHP application on the production. It is working on my and my friend's localhost. On the production I got the following error when trying to access different controllers:

**Error: Call to a member function find() on a non-object

File: /app/Controller/GroupsController.php

Line: 10**

```
<?php
class GroupsController extends AppController {

var $name = 'Groups';
var $displayField = 'name';
var $helpers = array('Paginator', 'Html', 'Form');

function index() {
    $groups = $this->Group->find('all');
    $members = $this->Group->GroupMember->find('all', array('order' => array('GroupMember.date_checked DESC'))); //Line 10!
    $owners = $this->Group->GroupContact->find('all', array('conditions' => array('GroupContact.owner' => 1)));
    $this->set(compact('groups', 'members', 'owners')); 
}
```

It looks like it fails to read GroupMember as an object.

**Model - groupMember.php**

```
<?php
class GroupMember extends AppModel{
var $name = 'GroupMember';
var $belongsTo = array(
    'Group' => array(
        'className' => 'Group',
        'foreignKey' => 'group_id'
    )
);
}
?>
```

**Model - group.php**

```
<?php
class Group extends AppModel{
var $name = 'Group';
var $hasMany = array(
    'GroupMember' => array(
        'className' => 'GroupMember',
        'foreignKey' => 'id',
    )
);
}
?>
```

You can see the errors on the http://www.thesupergroupproject.com/groups

Again - the project is working both on my localhost and my friend's localhost. What could be causing the error?

Comment: First up, the link to your code is already broken - you shouldn't be adding non-permanent links to your questions on SO.  Anyway,  as your code has been tested on two systems already, I'd be starting by making sure your production system isn't the problem.  Is there any version mismatch between your production system and your other two machines with any of the LAMP stack (Apache, Mysql & PHP) maybe?

Comment: I was deploying a different project in Cake on the same server and it worked properly before.

Comment: Same version of Cake?  There's been few changes in the past that have caught me like that.  Is that how your models are capitalised?  Naming conventions changed between 1.3 and 2, if it's a 2.0+ app it they should be `GroupMember.php` and `Group.php`.

Comment: Just had the thought too - that could be the problem if your development machines are Windows (case-insensitive), but the production server unix (case-sensitive).

Comment: @Daniel good thought I will check it. The cache is cleared also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Model names should be `CamelCase`. I suspect you are on windows or some other opperating system that is `case insensitive`, while your production is Linux which is `case sensitive`

Also when using 2.x there is no need for the $name property in models, this was for PHP4.x support which has been dropped.

Your relation with `'foreignKey' => 'id'` seems to be incorrect, GroupMember should be related by the `group_id` field.